# React JS npm start giving port busy ,but it is free

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, port, npm-start

My react app when I run '**npm star**t' gives port busy. Even if a change the port same problem occurs.
There's no problem in code as when I created new react app , encountered the same problem.
**Sudo lsof -i:port** gives no process running and other node js app(other than react) is also running perfectly.

**sudo nano /etc/hosts/ content is also okay.**
127.0.0.1 localhost

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": " react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4035

Comment: not able to solve the issue with that.

Comment: I believe you should open issue in github so the developers will be able to trace your problem and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a new terminal and running (assuming port is 3000):

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:3000)
```

Then try npm run start again